# What to do with edit summaries placed in the post itself?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

Is it generally appropriate to remove edit summaries from within the content in [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31164090/4)? Would it ever not be appropriate to remove them? In what cases?

Example:

> ...
>
> EDIT: Changed readonly to disabled because readonly never gets added.
>
> EDIT 2: Removed the attribute name repetition, that I added due to old
>   habits.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Is it recommended to notify the answer “Edits” with an heading followed by the edit content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230692)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just burn this with fire.  There's no need for information about *what an edit changed* to be in the question; it's already in the revision history for anyone who cares to see it.  Of course, not everything anyone says after an "Edit: " notation is describing *why* they edited, often they're just including additional information, so it's only the word "edit" that needs to be removed.

Comment: In this particular case they're old edits. But if they're recent edits, it might be worthwile to @-ping the editor, and ask them to put edit summaries only in the "edit summary" box.

Comment: @S.L.Barth If the editor wasn't the OP, then sure (as that's a pretty big problem if they're making inappropriate edits, but it doesn't happen much as if it's a <2k user the edit would typically get declined if it included this), if it's the OP (and it almost always is) then they'll be notified of the edit so all you really need is a revision note explaining why these should be removed.